# Find view by id is not working in fragment method android

Tags: android

why the "find view by id" is not working in `fragment` any one want to tell me that what wrong with this

[image: sample image]

Comment: Please post code as code, not picture.
Also, please be describe 'working' and 'not working' more accurately.

Comment: Simple: you're misspelling the method name. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get imageView in onCreateView before return view:

```
imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
return view;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the problem ? Please explain

Comment: findView'b'y'i'd  (R.layout.imageView2)  wrong typing and `R.layout`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.id);
```

Comment: This won't work because the fragment's view is not added to the activity's view hierarchy yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's R.id.imageView2 not R.layout.imageView2. Correct it! Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Format your Fragment class as below

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {

        ImageView imageview;   // declare here
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, parentViewGroup, false);
           imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView); // initialize here
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is v? `v.findViewById()`